# Adding a QgsLayoutItemTextTable and to a lyout do not give the opportunity to further modify the table from the layout

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, properties, object

I am trying something like this:

```
table1pg2 = QgsLayoutItemTextTable(layout)
layout.addMultiFrame(table1pg2)
cols = [QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn(),QgsLayoutTableColumn()]
cols[0].setHeading('a')
cols[1].setHeading('b')
cols[2].setHeading('c\'')
cols[3].setHeading('d')
cols[4].setHeading('e')
cols[5].setHeading('f')
cols[6].setHeading('g')
cols[7].setHeading('h')

table1pg2.setColumns(cols)
 
for feat in cat_feat: 
    table1pg2.addRow([str(feat[4]),str(feat[7]),str(feat[28]),str(feat[15]),str(feat[16]),str(feat[20]),str(feat[21]),str(feat[22])])

# Base class for frame items, which form a layout multiframe item.
frame = QgsLayoutFrame(layout, table1pg2)
frame.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, PosY, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters),page=1)
frame.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(30, 30), True)
table1pg2.addFrame(frame)
```

In order to add a table to the layout.
Later on in the code i print and add the layout to the project, but when i open the layout in order to manually edit the table the table object has no properties and therefore cannot be edited.
I suppose this is due to the fact that I am adding a text table objext instead of a fixed table object, wich unfortunatelly i cannot succeed to add.
Can anyone help?